# Find optimal case size for a product without incurring an overcharge

Tags: geometry

Given a product with box dimensions *l, w, h* I need to find the optimal case size those boxes will fit into such that  $2l+2w+h<105$ to avoid being charged for oversized shipping fees while also maximizing the number of boxes in the case.

So given $[l,w,h]$ I want to find the case dimensions $[a, b, c]$ that fit the maximum number of boxes.
To find that I need to find $[i, j, k]$, the number of boxes that can fit in the case in each dimension.

$$[a, b, c] = [il, jw, kh]$$
$$2li + 2wj+ kh< 105$$

since $i, j, k$ will have multiple answers I need to pick the combination which has the greatest product, which would be the greatest number of boxes that fit into the case. I'm not sure how to write that out in math notation.

So to bullet out the needs:

- I need to find a case that maximizes the number of boxes that fit into it
- That case cannot incur an overcharge
- The boxes cannot be rotated
- This solution will be applied to many, many boxes

To test a solution I would expect that:

- a box with l = 25, w = 25, and h = 4 would have a solution that is [1, 1, 1] (ijk), or [25, 25, 4] (abc)
- a box with l = 25, w = 25, and h = 5 would have no solution
- a box with l = 10, w = 20, and h = 4 would have a solution that is [2, 1, 6] (ijk) or [20, 20, 24] (abc)

I tackled the problem in R and came up with the function below which works, but I feel there has to be a more elegant way to do this than essentially a simulated trial and error approach.

````
optim <- function(l, w, h) {
  max_unit = 105
  
  x.l = seq(0, max_unit, l)
  x.w = seq(0, max_unit, w)
  x.h = seq(0, max_unit, h)
  
  possible_dims <- list()
  
  for (i in seq_along(x.l)) {
    for (j in seq_along(x.w)) {
      base_charge <- (2*i*l + 2*j*w)
      
      k = sapply(seq_along(x.h), \(k) x.h[k] + base_charge)
      
      ki = which(k < 105)
      if (length(ki) < 1) break()
      k = which.max(k[ki])[1]-1 # first index is 0 
      
      possible_dims <- c(possible_dims, list(c(i, j, k)))
    } # end for j x.w
  } # end for i x.l
  
  if (length(possible_dims) == 0)
    return()
  
  ijk = possible_dims[[which.max(sapply(possible_dims, \(x) prod(x)))[1]]]
  i = ijk[1]
  j = ijk[2]
  k = ijk[3]
  new_case = c(l, w, h) * possible_dims[[which.max(sapply(possible_dims, \(x) prod(x)))]]
  
  new_case
}
```
````

Comment: Can you put all of your constraints in words. It’s difficult to try to read your code to figure what it’s doing. As far as I can tell the optimal case size is like a nanometer cube so you can fit billions within your box. What’s the size of your box, what’s the size of the case? Why are there two h’s in your formula. What have you tried purely mathematically? What was the output of your program?

Comment: I gave it a shot, but I'm afraid my math notation is pretty subpar. If it's interpretable at all I'm very open to suggestions.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to improve it several ways. The second $h$ in the first formula should probably be a $w$. Can the small boxes be rotated - that is, can we use any of the three dimensions for the height or width or length? Is this a one off question, or will you need to solve it often for different input numbers? Please describe one possible packing (not necessarily the optimal one.

Comment: @EthanBolker thanks for the precise edit suggestions. Changes made.

Comment: The edit is clear. I doubt there's an elegant mathematical solution. There might be a more elegant way to structure the code (I haven't looked for one). Given the fact that you have code that works I think the problem now has only mathematical interest and it may not be interesting enough to attract attention.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Your first formula $2l+2w+h<105$ is confusing since you just define l,w,h as constants. I recommend different variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an integer optimization problem. In general, those are hard to explicitly solve.

To put your problem succinctly, you’re given some constants $l,w,h$ and are looking for positive integer $i,j,k$ which maximize $ijk$ given that
$$ 2li+2wj+hk<105$$

The simplest method is to loop through $i,j$. For each such pair, there’s a maximum $k$ that fits the constraint.

By AMGM, you get that
$$3 (4lwhijk)^{1/3}<105$$
$$ijk<\frac{35^3}{4lwh}$$
$$ijk<\frac{10718.75}{lwh}$$

This gives an upper bound of how well you can potentially do where you achieve that bound when $2li=2wj=hk=35$ although that’s impossible due to the integer constraint. In practice you can probably get pretty close to optimal just by testing integer values of $(i,j,k)$ near $(35/(2l),35/(2w),35/h)$. This approximation would work better if 105 were larger and when l,w,h are small.